# findOneAndUpdate return null upon insertion?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I want is:

1. return `1` if insertion succeeds even though the document doesn't exist before.
2. return `1` if update succeeds

But I can't seem to achieve this with `findOneAndUpdate` which only returns a result if the document exists and is successfully updated.

My query:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { email: email },
  { $set: { verified: 1 } },
  { upsert: true }
).exec(callback);
```

Comment: Look at the [**`WriteResult`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/WriteResult/) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could access the native driver to call the underlying collection's **[`updateOne()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateOne)** or **[`updateMany()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#updateMany)** method which will return the full response from Mongo in the **[`updateWriteOpCallback`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpCallback)** callback as a **[`updateWriteOpResult`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#~updateWriteOpResult)** object that you can use. For example

```
User.collection.updateOne(
    { "email": email },
    { "$set": { "verified": 1 } },
    { "upsert": true },
    function(err, result) {

        // The number of documents that matched the filter.
        console.log(result.matchedCount); 

        // The number of documents that were modified.    
        console.log(result.modifiedCount);  

        // The number of documents upserted.  
        console.log(result.upsertedCount);   

        // The total count of documents scanned. 
        console.log(result.result.n);     

        // The total count of documents modified.
        console.log(result.result.nModified); 
    }
);
```

In this case you most probably need to check the `result.result.nModified` and `result.upsertedCount` properties to make the above call.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the result to be the updated document, you need to modify your query to look like this:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  { email: email },
  { $set: { verified: 1 } },
  { upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true }
).exec(callback);
```

The `returnNewDocument` property will make the callback return the updated document instead of the original.  In the case of an upsert on a non-existing document, it will return the new document instead of an empty set.